# replace old furnace blower motor with a new one but the wires are different

Tags: hvac

[image]It is an old Rheem RGAA-100C furnace, On the old motor the wires was: White, Brown, Red, Black and Blue. On the new Motor it has Brown, Brown/White, Black, Red, White, and Blue. I don't know how to wire it back. They do not make the old motor anymore, this motor was the replacement. Could you please help.

On the circuit diagram on the motor says:

- Br/Wh to Cap.
- Br to Cap.
- Wh to Line.
- [Blk (Hi) or Blue (Med) or Red (Low)] to Line.

Comment: Do you still have the old one, or know its make and model number? Did it have a circuit diagram? Do you have the new one's make and model number, and does it have a diagram?

Comment: Rheem RGAA-100C is our furnace and no, I don't have the old motor anymore. The wires from the motor goes into a junction box on the blower housing, the main power leads come the junction box above and then goes into the blower housing junction box. On the circuit diagram on the motor says:  Br/Wh to Cap., Br to Cap., Wh to Line, [ Blk (Hi) or Blue (Med) or Red (Low) ]  to Line. The power leads that come into the junction box are: Red, Black and White, From what I see, I should put the power leads white to cap, black to black on motor wires, so what do I do with the power leads red?

Answer (score 2):

There should be a schematic printed on a sticker on the motor.  Without knowing the make and model, or looking at the diagram. I'm guessing based on other motors.

One common "standard" is as follows:

- White = grounded (neutral) (*clockwise*).
- Black = High speed.
- Blue = Medium speed (*medium low*).
- Red = Low speed.
- Brown = Run capacitor.
- Brown w/ white = Run capacitor.
- Green = Ground.
- *Yellow = Medium speed.*
- *Purple = Grounded (neutral) (anticlockwise)*.

*Optional wiring available on some motors.*

However, without the make and model, or the schematic, this is just a guess.

---

Update

The two brown wires (Br and Br/Wh) should be connected to the capacitor. If you don't have one, you may need to install one. The brown wire from the old motor should have been connected to it, so try to remember where you removed the brown wire from.

The white wire from the motor, should connect to the white wire in the junction box. This is L2/neutral, and completes the circuit.

The remaining wires are for selecting the motor speed (Blk, Blue, Red), so you're going to have to figure out which speed you should be using.  If you can remember which color wire was connected to the red wire in the junction box, that should be the same color wire to hook back up. Typically the blower is run at low speed when in heating mode, but that's no guarantee that *your* equipment was set up that way.

I wasn't able to locate any documentation on your equipment, and without a schematic I can't be any more specific. If you could include a good photo of the schematic, I could *show* you where to make the connections. You should be able to find a schematic in the manufacturer's documentation, or on the furnaces access panel.

Comment: Rheem RGAA-100C is our furnace and no, I don't have the old motor anymore. The wires from the motor goes into a junction box on the blower housing, the main power leads come the junction box above and then goes into the blower housing junction box. On the circuit diagram on the motor says:  Br/Wh to Cap., Br to Cap., Wh to Line, [ Blk (Hi) or Blue (Med) or Red (Low) ]  to Line. The power leads that come into the junction box are: Red, Black and White, From what I see, I should put the power leads white to cap, black to black on motor wires, so what do I do with the power leads red?

Comment: i do have a pic but i was not sure how to get it to you.

Comment: [This](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/a/524/33) should explain how to add an image.

Comment: I tryied to added the pics of the motor diagram and the wire diagram for the unit above, but it would only let me save one of them, this the diagram of the unit.

Comment: @Elmore Did you locate the capacitor in the furnace?

Comment: The capacitor is locate on the blower house assy with the junction box together. I can send a pic, if you want me too.

Comment: I know all the wires have to be wirenut together in the junction box on the blower housing,  Brown wire goes to the one side of the capacitor, and the other wire, Brown/White wire goes to the other side.  My question is does the White wire from the motor go to the White wire from the power junction box, Black wire from the motor goes to the other Black wire from the power junction box, and the Red wire from the motor goes to the Red wire from the power junction box?

Comment: my furnace motor only ran for a little bit then shut off, did I wire it wrong?

Comment: @Elmore Without being there, it sounds like you wired it properly. When you wired it, there were only two wires on the capacitor (Br, Br/Wh), right?Why did you replace the motor in the first place? Is it possible that whatever problem killed the first motor, still exists and killed the replacement as well? Have you tested the capacitor to make sure its good?

Comment: how do you test the capacitor?

Comment: A lot of help here and no up votes?  A cap can be checked with an ohm meter to see if it charges, not accurate but an indication if the ohms value starts increasing reverse the leads and it should start decreasing a fixed value is a bad capacitor.